# How to use preg_replace to remove HTML tags and attributes but keep some content within

Tags: preg-replace

Suppose I have the following text in a HTML file called `index.html`:

```
<FONT FACE="Times New Roman, serif">
  <FONT SIZE=3>
    <SPAN STYLE="background: transparent">
      This is my text and it spans lines
      within a text file
      like this.
    </SPAN>
  </FONT>
</FONT>
```

I want to strip the FONT tags and FONT attributes, together with the
FONT close tags, but maintain everything in between, and output to a
file `output.html`.

I wrote a short PHP program which I thought would do this, but its not
finding the pattern string:

```php
$pattern = '<FONT FACE="Times New Roman, serif"><FONT SIZE=3>((.|\n)*)</FONT></FONT>';
$replacement = '\1';
file_put_contents('./output.html', preg_replace($pattern, $replacement,
                  file_get_contents('./index.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)));
```

The pattern isn't being found. Can anyone spot an issue with the code?

I'm using `>((.|\n)*)` in order to capture all the characters, whether
newline or not.

Comment: I also tried setting $replacement to $1, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('~<font[^>]*face=\"Times\s+New\s+Roman\s*\,\s*serif\"[^>]*>\s*<font[^>]*size=\'?3\"?[^>]*>(.*?)<\/font>~is', '\1', YOUR_STRING);
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this is that it will replace ALL of my FONT occurences and I only want to replace those that have Times New Roman, Serif and font size = 3.

Comment: I modified regex which you want.